# How to assign macro to button without using "active sheet" in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the macro assigned to a button from a different sheet than where the button is. This is how far I've gotten:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Macro2"
End Sub
```

However, the above code requres me to be on the active sheet. I have tried the following:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "Macro2"
End Sub
```

However, this will give me an "*Object doesn't support this property or method*" error.

Why doesn't it work when "ActiveSheet" is replaced with "Sheet1"?

And why can't I collect the two lines of code into one line?:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).OnAction = "Macro2"
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, simple try:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction = "Macro2"
```

Of course, a macro named "Macro2" should exist in a **standard module**. If in a sheet code module, the sheet `CodeName` is necessary in front of the macro name (`"Sheet1.Macro2"`)...

Comment: @Elio Fernandes I am afraid you do not understand what is it about, no offence... In the above way you can assign the "Macro2" `Sub` to a "Button 1" shape situated on `Sheet1`, being **wherever you want to be**. I mean, in a standard module on in another sheet code module, if you understand what that mean... Selecting the shape is a bad habit, anyhow, but the above code **does not select anything**.

Comment: Thank you so much FaneDuru. This worked! The recorded macro threw me off. Thanks for getting me back on track. :-)